# CCSpriteBatchNode applying Shader?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es-2.0, ccspritebatchnode

I'm applying a shader to my BatchNode with cocos2d 2.0.

I updated the ccV3F_C4B_T2F struct to hold a new uniform, so it now looks like this:

typedef struct _ccV3F_C4B_T2F
{

```
ccVertex3F      vertices;           

ccColor4B       colors;         

ccTex2F         texCoords;      

    ccVertex2F              NewCoords;
```

} ccV3F_C4B_T2F;

I added a new property value to plist of my CCspritebatchnode, which is the value that i want to pass to the shader.
So when the batchnode gets the offset ,color rect, etc., of each frame. It will also get the value that I need passed through. that worked.

I then took the values from the Batchnodes plist and modified 'updatetransform' to recieve the values.
so it looks something like this:

```
 quad_.bl.NewCoords = (ccVertex2F) { newCoords.x, newCoords.y };
        quad_.br.NewCoords = (ccVertex2F) { newCoords.x, newCoords.y };
        quad_.tl.NewCoords = (ccVertex2F) { newCoords.x, newCoords.y };
        quad_.tr.NewCoords = (ccVertex2F) { newCoords.x, newCoords.y };
```

I subclassed CCSpriteBatchNode and applied the shader:

vertex shader:

```
\n\
attribute vec4 a_position;                          \n\
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;                          \n\
attribute vec4 a_color;                             \n\
attribute vec2 a_newcoords;                          \n\
\n\
varying lowp vec4 v_fragmentColor;                  \n\
varying mediump vec2 v_texCoord;                    \n\
varying mediump vec2 v_newcoords;                   \n\
\n\
void main()                                         \n\
{                                                   \n\
   gl_Position = CC_MVPMatrix * a_position;     \n\
   v_fragmentColor = a_color;                       \n\
   v_texCoord = a_texCoord;                     \n\
   v_newcoords = a_newcoords;                        \n\
 }                                                      \n\
";
```

fragment shader:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif

varying vec4 v_fragmentColor;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
varying vec2 v_newcoords;

 uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main()
{
     vec2 texCoord = v_texCoord;
     vec4 texColor  = texture2D(u_texture, texCoord);

     vec2 MoveBy = vec2(v_newcoords.x, v_newcoords.y);
     vec4 Color1  = texture2D(u_texture, vec2(v_texCoord.x - MoveBy.x , v_texCoord.y));

     vec4 finalColor = vec4(texColor.r, texColor.g, Color1.b, texColor.a);
     gl_FragColor =  finalColor;
 }
```

The vertex shader gets the 'attribute vec2 a_newcoords;' correctly, but I can't access the 'varying v_newcoords' from the fragment shader.

Does someone know what I might be doing wrong??

Comment: Curious how you ascertained that "The vertex shader gets the 'attribute vec2 a_newcoords;' correctly" ...

Comment: In the vertex shader, I wrote :                                       " v_texCoord = a_texCoord - v_newcoords.x;". The frames came out as if they had an offset, the amount of the offset was consistent with the value of a_newcoords. So for example one frame would have a_newcoords value of 30 another 35 another 25, the values all matched up to the amount that was subtracted. Do you have any suggestions to what i might be doing wrong??